# Linux VirtualBox - Machine group conflicts with a virtual machine name

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, fedora

Machine group '/Linux/New Group' conflicts with a virtual machine name.

I'm trying to import a virtual machine that my University provided me with. I don't have any groups made in VB, and I have no idea what to do, to make it work.
I can import CentOS8, but not Debian 10 Buster. With Fedora 30 it tells me the same thing.

So I download the machine, with .ova extension, then I click on import and it shows me this:

[Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVAtT.png)

Comment: Please explain in greater detail what you're doing and list the errors.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1833731/edit) your post - comments like that are hard to read.